# What song plays at 1:21:01 in the movie "Futari no Hero" ("Two Heroes")?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

In *My Hero Academia: Two Heroes* movie, at 1:21:01 when the other kids arrive and start attacking the villain, a certain song is played from the time

> Bakugo says "*What are you doing getting all beat up by such a damn lame last boss?*" until the villain tangles All Might (practically during the time All Might goes Plus Ultra).

As far as I know, the song is not even included in the movie's OST discs.

Does anyone know what the name of that song is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the Song is "Here" By Yuly

Comment: That's the one, thanks! (Although I'm confused why they used a track from S2's OST but didn't include it in the movie's)